# How to change the audio track of a video on the fly using ffmpeg in c++?

Tags: android, c++, audio, video, ffmpeg

I am trying to develop a media player application in android. I am using dolphin player's code as reference. But i don't know how to change the audio and subtitle track on the fly while playing a video . using command line of ffmpeg it's possible but how to do it with ffmpeg c++ code?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Video file is a container that have a bunch of streams. First, you have to open video file and extract streams information (error checking avoided for smaller code):

```
AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx;
av_open_input_file( &pFormatCtx, argv[1], NULL, 0, NULL );
av_find_stream_info( pFormatCtx );
```

Now you can iterate streams and find all audio streams:

```
for ( i=0; i != pFormatCtx->nb_streams; i++ )
{
   if (pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type==CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO) audioStreams.push_back( i );
}
```

Select which stream you would like to play and get a pointer to the codec and open it:

```
AVCodecContext* aCodecCtx = pFormatCtx->streams[SelectedAudioStream]->codec;
AVCodec* aCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(aCodecCtx->codec_id);
avcodec_open(aCodecCtx, aCodec);
```

Decode the stream as usual after that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The above scenario is the case when multiple audio streams are embedded with the video file. I have another doubt whether we can choose an external audio file and sync it with the video playing. For example if i have an english movie and i have external tracks of other languages for the movie , is it possible to change the audio track by choosing the available language tracks?

Comment: In case of external files the sync is completely up to you. Of coarse it is possible, however there are too few details in the question to answer it in this way.

Comment: Suppose we select an external audio track while playing a video , is it like we would create a new object of AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx;
av_open_input_file( &pFormatCtx, argv[1], NULL, 0, NULL );
av_find_stream_info( pFormatCtx ); and get the audio stream index and set it to the currently playing video's audio stream and resume playing.. is my understanding right?

Comment: Could you please help me to get the audio track's title from the streams? i.e., if it's a multi language video file then we would have option to select "Language1","Language2" etc.. how will we get that name?

Comment: In AVStream structure (http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/data.html#AVStream) there is a field ``char language [4]`` - use it wisely :)

Comment: Thanks for your comments..in latest ffmpeg's AVStream structure variable language is not there, instead there is a metadata variable from which we could get some information.. For reference : https://lists.ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-cvslog/2011-July/038676.html